# Run a "breakpoint command list" for all breakpoints /iterate over breakpoints [GDB]

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a way to iterate over all my breakpoints in GDB and set a "command list" [ http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_35.html ] ? I have about a 100 breakpoints and I want to run a set of commands for each of these breakpoints. Is anyone aware of how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: this might help you [http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html)

Comment: No, I already read that. I know there are commands for enabling and disabling all breakpoints. What I am talking about is "Breakpoint command Lists" for all breakpoints
http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_35.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cond <break-point#> <statement to execute>`

are you looking something like above?

EDIT:

you can try breakpoint range. From above link:-

> > Some gdb commands accept a range of breakpoints on which to operate. A breakpoint range is either a single breakpoint number, like `5', or two such numbers, in increasing order, separated by a hyphen, like`5-7'. When a breakpoint range is given to a command

Comment: What you gave is a simple conditional statement for a breakpoint. I am looking for executing a set of commands for all breakpoints. For a single breakpoint the way I do it is "commands <breakpointNum> [return] p "broke" [return] end"
http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_35.html

Comment: Oh, yep, got it. I tried this "commands 1-100 [return] p "broke" [return] end" and works for all breakpoints. Thanks ravi